# NoClassDefFoundError com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TreeNode -- json schema validation

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

Getting the below mention exception in json-schema-validator 2.1.7 jar:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TreeNode
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:466)
```

I am using:

- json-schema-validator 2.1.7 jar
- json-schema-core 1.1.8 jar
- jackson-coreutils 1..0 jar
- jackson-databind-2.2.2 jar

Code snippet is given below:

```
            System.out.println(" inside json validation -- 0");
            JsonNode data = JsonLoader.fromString(responseString);
            System.out.println(" inside json validation -- 1");
            JsonNode jsonSchema = JsonLoader.fromResource(schemafilePath);
            System.out.println(" inside json validation -- 2");
            JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
            System.out.println(" inside json validation -- 3");
            JsonSchema schema = factory.getJsonSchema(jsonSchema);
            System.out.println(" inside json validation -- 4");
            ProcessingReport report = schema.validate(data);
```

Comment: I think you might have duplicate jars ?

Comment: are you using eclipse?

Comment: No, am using Intellij Idea...

Comment: Are you building with Maven? If so, could you show the `groupId`'s as well, or the relevant POM details?

Comment: No am not building with maven, am adding it as jar in library folder.

Comment: OK, in that case it somewhat harder to obtain all the dependencies - but that's exactly your problem. Find out which JAR contains the missing class and add it to the lib folder. Repeat.

Comment: Ya that is the problem, now I added all the dependency jars also.. all issues solved. working fine now. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I recall correctly `jackson-databind` has a transitive dependency to `jackson-core` where `TreeNode` should be. Check your `.m2` folder for the presence of:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and if it's there I agree that you might have a classpath problem, such as a previous version of `jackson-core` first in the classpath.

Cheers,

Comment: R.Bystrup : Thats the issue after adding jackson-core 2.2.2 and   jackson-annotations 2.2.2 those class not found exceptions got solved. Thanks..

Comment: Now getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/fge/Frozen"  exception...

Comment: @user1919581 Hey how did u get around the  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/fge/Frozen" exception. ??

Comment: @raynaya that exception occurred coz one of the dependent jar is not there... it got solved by placing all the dependent jar files in lib...

Answer (score 0):

[ + ] libs/jackson-core-2.9.9.jar